# python: os.getenv returns none with sudo?

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables

I've set environment variable `LIBRARY_PATH` in `/etc/bash.bashrc` by adding `export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LIBRARY_PATH` at the end.

When I try to get the env-variable from python:

```
ipython
import os
print os.getenv('LIBRARY_PATH')
```

Everything works well, it prints `/usr/local/cuda/lib64:`.

BUT when I invoke ipython with `sudo`:

```
sudo ipython
import os
pront os.getenv('LIBRARY_PATH')
```

I get nothing. I guess this is about env-variables accross users, but what is the ditails? I set `LIBRARY_PATH` in `/etc/bash.bashrc` which is said to be the 'system wide bashrc file'.

So how can I get the correct env-variable with sudo in python ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want `sudo` to pass through environment variables (which is generally considered a security hazard), use `sudo -E`.

Note that it is `bash` which executes the commands in the bashrc files. `ipython` is not `bash`, obviously, and `sudo` does not start up a shell process, much less a bash process, just in order to run the command you are requesting it to run. So none of your bashrc files are going to be executed by the `sudo` command or in the `sudo` subprocess. Of course, you can tell `sudo` to run a bash process:

```
sudo bash -c ipython
```

However, `bash` does not execute startup files if it detects that it is being run in a sudo process.

For more information on how `sudo` cleans the environment, type `man 5 sudoers` and skip down to the `Command environment` section.

Comment: Thank you for your patient answering, problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

If you set the environment variable in /root/.bash_profile, then you will probably get the desired behavior when using sudo.

Comment: @rici  's answer solved my problem, thank you as well.

Comment: This does not work